# ASP.NET SQL regarding the statement

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a table with columns `Type`, `HalfYearPrice`, `FullYearPrice`.

On the form I have 2 radiolists, one each for `Type` and `Price`.

Say if a person chooses the type, then chooses the `HalfYearPrice`

I'm stuck on how to write the SQL statement. Currently I got

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE Type = @type 
  AND *something* = @price
```

Where `@type` and `@price` are selected values from radiolists.

But what do I put in place of *something* as it could be either table column HalfYearPrice or FullYearPrice

Comment: `and @price in (HalfYearPrice, FullYearPrice)`?

Comment: Use two different queries?

Comment: I'm not clear on if you want to filter by HalfYearPrice and FullYearPrice at the same time, or if you want to selectively filter on one of them.

Comment: Upvoted @jarlh in case that's what you're looking for. If not, clarify your question with a sample table and expected output? Not quite sure what the goal is

Comment: @Senbon, did that solve your problem?

Comment: @jarlh yes it did :)

Comment: Great, I added that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search HalfYearPrice and FullYearPrice at the same time, use `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE Type = @type 
  AND @price in (HalfYearPrice, FullYearPrice)
```